# Why is this clipping happening

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Notice in the code i didn't put any clipping on the grid, why is this rectangle being displayed clipped to the size of the grid.

I added the offset just to show that even if i move it to the side the fill of the grid is not red.

```
    <Grid Height="135" Width="162">
        <Rectangle Width="300" Height="249" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#FFDB1919" UseLayoutRounding="False">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection LocalOffsetX="-42"/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>

        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grids have clipping of content on by default.

The quickest fix is to place the rectangle in a canvas (which has no clipping by default):

```
<Grid Height="135" Width="162">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Width="300" Height="249" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#FFDB1919" UseLayoutRounding="False" StrokeThickness="5">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection LocalOffsetX="-42"/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what happening here:

```
1. WPF layout is done. it will place the 
   rectangle in the center as it was specified.
2. The rectangle will be clipped by the Grid.
3. The Projection transformation is applied after all this stuff.
   In your case you did move already clipped rectangle by -42 pixels
```

Comment: Why is it clipping? There is a property called clip which I can set if I want the grid to clip its content, why would it clip without setting that property. In other words, what can I do that it should not clip the rectangle and let freely display in fits full width?

Comment: In normal cases clipping is a necessity for the grid this is why it is the default behaviour. You problem is not the clipping your problem is using Projection. In normal cases you should not modify this thing. If you want a rectangle outside the grid you need to use different means for that.

Comment: And what other means would that be?